# What makes this question a duplicate?

Tags: discussion

I created 2 questions dealing with Roth IRAs.

- A general question about [keeping an emergency fund in a Roth IRA](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/80704/29254).
- A [question](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/80828/29254) asking for an explanation for the rules that apply if one attempts to make Roth IRA contributions and withdrawals in the same year.

The second question seems to have been closed as a duplicate of the first.

While I will admit that the primary reason I personally am interested in the second question is because the answer could have an affect on my decision regarding keeping my emergency fund in a Roth IRA (and I happen to mention that in the second question itself), none of the answers to my first question really fully answer my second question.

Is the fact that my second question happens to mention the first enough to make it a duplicate regardless of the whether any answers to the first question really answer the second? What if I just edit out any mention of the first question from the second one?

Answer (score 1):

I agree they are different questions and have reopened the closed one.